# Desktop file doesn't work

Tags: gnome, permissions, .desktop, paths

I'm trying to make a desktop file for vcvRack. I have the program and other files saved in `~/.Rack/`. The program launches fine when I double click it or launch in from terminal using `./Rack`.

The file `~/.local/share/applications/Rack.desktop` contains the following.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Rack
Comment=bleep bloop
Exec=/home/uname/.Rack/Rack
Icon=/home/uname/.Rack/icon-3.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Music;
```

It shows up in search with icon and all, but it doesn't actually launch. I've tried `chmod +x Rack.desktop` and `sudo chmod +x Rack.desktop`, though I don't think either should be necessary.

I have other nearly identical desktop files for other programs that run fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please run `gtk-launch ~/.local/share/applications/Rack.desktop` from a terminal, and see if the output contains anything useful. You are basically launching your desktop file from a command line this way.

Comment: `gtk-launch: no such application /home/uname/.local/share/applications/Rack.desktop` ... Same result for all other desktop files btw.

Comment: That would suggest that the desktop file doesn't exist, although the path is the same as what you mentioned.

Comment: Rather try `gtk-launch Rack` . You do not supply a path with gtk-launch. This is not a terminal application? Try adding `Terminal=true` to the launcher

Comment: BUMP: @vanadium I have the EXACT same problem (i.e. also Rack). `gtk-launch rack` returns `~/opt/Rack2Free/Rack: error while loading shared libraries: libRack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. But, it launches fine when running the file Rack from its home directory. Adding `Terminal=true` results in no output at all when I run with gtk-launch. I looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480764/linux-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-s  but I am not sure I exactly what applies here.

Comment: Update: If I add `Path=~/opt/Rack2Free/` to rack.desktop, gtk-launch actually launches Rack but with a bunch of errors, but the gui and everything shows up. If I remove the Path variable, the libRack.so error is back and no gui shows. Either way, the launcher found by pressing the super key never works at all, no gui or anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution (tl;dr):

Add `Path=/home/username/opt/Rack2Free` to `rack.desktop` , i.e. replaced with whatever path you have to the Rack working directory where you'll find the file `Rack`. Then possibly restart the computer (or log out and in).

### Details:

I had the exact same issue with creating a desktop file for VCV Rack. It would show up among other applications when pressing `super`, but just wouldn't launch (nothing happens). However, launching by running the file `~/opt/Rack2Free/Rack` would work.

I solved it with the following `rack.desktop` file placed in `~/.local/share/applications`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=VCVRack
Exec=/home/username/opt/Rack2Free/Rack
Path=/home/username/opt/Rack2Free
Icon=/home/username/opt/Rack2Free/res/icon.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Audio;Music
Keywords=Music
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.26
```

The key here is the 'Path'-variable. Before that, when I tried running `gtk-launch rack` in a terminal (see comments above) I got: `~/opt/Rack2Free/Rack: error while loading shared libraries: libRack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. So, even though the Exec-path was there, it could not find other files that it needed, so adding that Path to Rack's working directory and restarting the computer did the trick for me.

**Note:** For some reason before restarting the computer, launching with `gtk-launch rack` worked, but via launcher, i.e. `super` button, it did not work. But restarting fixed that.

---

(*Also: The errors I mentioned in the comments above I apparently get when running `./Rack` anyways, just that I don't usually run it via terminal, so I'm not used to seeing them. They are likely not relevant here but they are:*)

```
MidiInJack::initialize: JACK server not running?
MidiOutJack::initialize: JACK server not running?
RtAudio alsa: _NOT_ running realtime scheduling
RtAudio alsa: _NOT_ running realtime scheduling
ERROR: File doesn't exist or otherwise can't load file
ERROR: File doesn't exist or otherwise can't load file
...
```